# В данном предложении надо ставить запятую перед союзом "потому что"?

Tags: синтаксис

Не ругайте меня(,) потому что я и так стараюсь что есть мочи.

Answer (score 3):

**Не ругайте меня, потому что я и так стараюсь что есть мочи.**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным причины, **запятая ставится перед составным союзом ПОТОМУ ЧТО** (он не расчленяется и целиком относится к придаточной части).

**Примечание.** Выражение ***что есть мочи*** является устойчивым, имеет значение одного слова (очень стараюсь), запятая перед союзом ЧТО не ставится.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно нужна – сложноподчинённое предложение.

Comment: Я бы поставил запятую перед "потому", а не перед "что". А Вы запятую перед каким "что" предлагаете поставить? (Я, конечно, понимаю, перед каким, но было бы лучше сказать об этом в ответе.)

Comment: Я это и имел в виду, невнимательно вопрос прочитал. Тем более что и знак вопроса стоит перед "потому".